# How is the hold out set chosen in vowpal wabbit

Tags: logistic-regression, vowpalwabbit

I am using vowpal wabbit for logistic regression. I came to know that vowpal wabbit selects a hold out set for validation from the given training data. Is this set chosen randomly. I have a very unbalanced dataset with 100 +ve examples and 1000 -ve examples. I want to know given this training data, how vowpal wabbit selects the hold out examples?

How do I assign more weights to the +ve examples

Answer (score 5):

By default each 10th example is used for holdout (you can change it with `--holdout_period`,
see https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments#holdout-options).
This means the model trained with holdout evaluation on is trained only on 90% of the training data.
This may result in slightly worse accuracy.
On the other hand, it allows you to use `--early_terminate` (which is set to 3 passes by default),
which makes it easier to reduce the risk of overtraining caused by too many training passes.
Note that by default holdout evaluation is on, only if multiple passes are used (VW uses progressive validation loss otherwise).

As for the second question, you can add *importance weight* to the positive examples. The default importance weight is 1. See https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format